# Delete all lines after a specific line in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, text-extraction

I have this `.txt` file

```
ROTHSCHILD  = 81;        // Fondation Adolphe de Rothschild          ,                          2019
ONCOPOLE    = 82;        // Oncopole - Toulouse                      ,                          2019
GHRMSA      = 83;        // GHR  Mulhouse Sud-Alsace                 ,                          2019
CHDN        = 84;        // CH   du Nord - Luxembourg                ,                          2019
CAEN        = 85;        // CHU  de Caen                             ,                          2019
MONTELIMAR  = 86;        //                                          ,                          2019
PUYENVELAY  = 87;        //                                          ,                          2019
```

I want delete all lines after

```
CHDN        = 84;        // CH   du Nord - Luxembourg                ,                          2019
```

How can I do this ?

I tried this:

```
get-content txt.txt | % {$_ ; if($_ -eq "CHDN        = 84;        // CH   du Nord - Luxembourg                ,                          2019") {break }}
```

but break end my program, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely need to do something which tests each time.  I would use a `Do..Until` loop like this:

```
$txtData = get-content txt.txt
$stophere = 'CHDN        = 84;        // CH   du Nord - Luxembourg                ,                          2019'
$ctr = 0
Do
{
    $txtData[$ctr++] #Prints data line and increments counter
} Until ($txtData[$ctr] -eq $stophere)
```

Answer (score 1):

> but `break` ends my program

The reason is that **`break` in a *pipeline* doesn't exit the pipeline, it exits any enclosing *loop*** (`foreach`, `for`, `do`, and `while` statements), and if there is none, the script as a whole is exited.

- [This longstanding feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821) asks for introducing the ability to exit pipelines prematurely, but as of PowerShell [Core] 7.0 this feature doesn't exist.

However, you could simply **modify your approach to use a `foreach` *loop***, where `break` works as expected:

```
# The last line to include in the output.
$stopLine = 'CHDN        = 84;        // CH   du Nord - Luxembourg                ,                          2019'

# Output all lines up to and including the stop line.
# Simply assign to a variable to capture all output lines:
#   $linesOfInterest = foreach ($line ...) { ... }
# Or wrap in $(...) to send to a file.
#   $(foreach ($line ...) { ... }) | Set-Content ...
foreach ($line in Get-Content file.txt) {
  $line 
  if($line -eq $stopLine) {break }
}
```

---

Alternatively, use **a regex-based solution that captures all lines of interest as a single, multi-line string** (which you could split into lines with `-split '\r?\n'`, if needed):

```
# The last line to include in the output.
$stopLine = 'CHDN        = 84;        // CH   du Nord - Luxembourg                ,                          2019'

# Use the -match operator with a regex that that captures everything
# from the beginning of the the file through the stop line, inclusively.
if ((Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -match '(?sm).*^{0}$' -f [regex]::Escape($stopLine)) {
  # Output what was captured.
  # Append -split '\r?\n' to split into an array of lines.
  $Matches[0]
}
```

- `(?sm)` sets inline regex options `s` (make `.` match newlines too) and `m` (make `^` and `$` match the ends and beginnings of individual lines)
- `.*` matches any sequence of characters, including none
- `^{0}$` matches the escaped stop line (via [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape), to ensure that it is matched *literally*) in full, where `{0}` is the placeholder for the escaped line substituted by `-f`, the [string formatting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)
- If `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), succeeds, it populates the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), whose `0` entry contains what the regex matched in full.